# How to display multiple submit buttons horizontally with Laravel 4 Form::open()

Tags: css, forms, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Beginner here...

I have a search form, the results of which contain links to related items.  The related items are clickable insofar as there is a submit button to resubmit the search form with the related item's data pre-populated in the form's hidden fields.

All of the logic works fine.  Clicking the button resubmits the form and displays the data for the related items, etc.

My questions is how do I get the potentially multiple submit buttons to show up horizontally?

In my View I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <p>Additional Variations: 
        @if ($related['tall'])
            {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'doSearchCatalog', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('partnum', $related['tall']) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Tall', array('class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        @endif  
        @if ($related['petit'])
            {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'doSearchCatalog', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('partnum', $related['petit']) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Petit', array('class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        @endif
        @if ($related['matern'])
            {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'doSearchCatalog', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('partnum', $related['matern']) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Maternity', array('class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        @endif
        @if ($related['parent'])
            {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'doSearchCatalog', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('partnum', $related['parent']) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Standard', array('class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        @endif
    </p>
</div>
```

Which renders as:

```
<div class="row">
    <p>Additional Variations: 
        <form method="POST" action="http://intranet.amslab.local/catalog/search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cZl4Jt6ZNMAUJVhFa6ySN5P6MwMDHZyn6MQWxgvT">
            <input name="partnum" type="hidden" value="A311TL">
            <input class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="submit" value="Tall">
        </form>
        <form method="POST" action="http://intranet.amslab.local/catalog/search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cZl4Jt6ZNMAUJVhFa6ySN5P6MwMDHZyn6MQWxgvT">
            <input name="partnum" type="hidden" value="A311PE">
            <input class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="submit" value="Petit">
        </form>
    </p>
</div>
```

And looks like:

[image: Vertical Submit Buttons]

I'd like them to display horizontally.

I tried including the `hidden` and `submit` types within a single `Form::open() ... Form::close()` block, rather than the multiple blocks.  That worked for showing the submit buttons horizontally, but broke the logic, as both buttons (if there were two) submitted the data of the last one rendered.

Does it follow then that one form = one submit with the Laravel form builder?

I also tried (just grasping at straws here) enclosing the form in a `<div class="btn-group">` block, but to no avail.

This strikes me as likely a simple thing to accomplish but alas, my google/SO foo is failing me.

Is this possible to do with Laravel's form syntax?

Should I scrap the Laravel syntax and just write it html?  Would I face the same trouble either way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, the question is `CSS` related, if you want to show both submit/form horizontally (side by side) then you may try setting the form display property `display:inline-block` like ([**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7bgW/1/)) :

```
.row form { display:inline-block; }
```

You have two forms and both contains two submit buttons and both forms should be saty side by side to display submit buttons side by side, so, try to adjust your `css` style for the form most probably defined in a file `style.css`.

**Update :** Alternatively, you can also use inline style in both forms when using `::open()` method like:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'doSearchCatalog', 'method' => 'POST', 'style'=>'display:inline-block')) }}
```

Comment: Super!  I went with the first suggestion and it worked perfectly.  Incidentally, just to keep it as localized as possible, I just added a class to the "row" `<div class="row related">` and added to my `custom.css`, `.related form { display:inline-block; }`  Thank you very much :)